# How to set framerate of output video using ffmpeg in javascript

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

My code for javascript for ffmpeg is :

```
await ffmpeg.run("-i", "input.webm", "output.mp4");
```

What changes do i need to make in above code to set the framerate for the output video and also the video have audio too so that needs to be in sync. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What node library are you using to run ffmpeg? Why not have a look at the ffmpeg and the node library's documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `-r` output option:

```
await ffmpeg.run("-i", "input.webm", "-r", "25", "output.mp4");
```

`ffmpeg` will automatically include the audio.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can you suggest a much faster way of converting webm to mp4?

Comment: @RaviKundu Add the `-preset` option with an appropriate value. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset). Or assuming your input is VP9 + Opus, fastest method is to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux), and do not encode: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy output.mp4`. But make sure your ffmpeg is recent and test that your application can play the resulting file as not everything can handle VP9 + Opus in MP4.

Comment: thanks so much man you have been a great help

Comment: can you tell me if this will run on mobile browser like chrome, safari, etc..?

Comment: @RaviKundu H.264+AAC in MP4, yes. VP9+Opus in MP4, I don't know. You'll have to try it.